# References for Poisson and Lexis trials

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, bernoulli-trial

I have been trying to find more information on Poisson and Lexis trials (generalizations of Bernoulli trials), but I have failed to find anything outside of MathWorld (I went through a number of statistics books and was also unable to find anything)

Does anyone know of references which are known to contain a discussion of Poisson and Lexis trials?

Comment: Wow ... really? Nothing?

Comment: Try searching for "Lexis ratio" instead of "Lexis trial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an old 1927 paper "On Poisson's and Lexis's problem of probability of repeated trials" by Jordan Charles: http://arch.neicon.ru/xmlui/handle/123456789/1584111

See also a short article "The Meaning of Binomial Distribution" 
by A.W.F. Edwards: 
http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v186/n4730/abs/1861074a0.html

Comment: Thanks, Zurab. Somehow i missed your answer until now, but these references should do it.